# javascript price range on 2 items

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to add a price range like this

```
const priceRanges = [
  { min: 0, max: 100000 },
  { min: 100000, max: 500000 },
  { min: 500000, max: 1000000 },
  { min: 1000000, max: 5000000 },
  { min: 5000000, max: 10000000 },
  { min: 10000000, max: 25000000 },
  { min: 25000000, max: 50000000 },
  { min: 50000000, max: 100000000 },
  { min: 100000000, max: 500000000 },
  { min: 500000000, max: 1000000000 },
];
```

to my JavaScript.
I want the price ranges on the `startNewRound` function to pick any 2 items from the same price range and display their name image and value.
I tried hard to make this work but it always turns out in an error so I'm only left to come on here. I would really use some help.
Here is the full JavaScript code you might need:

```js
const items = [ 
  { name: "Lamborghini Hurracan", value: 400000, imageSrc: "https://i.ibb.co/D4s85gw/KURCINA.png"}, 
  { name: "Lamborghini Revuelto", value: 600000, imageSrc: "https://i.ibb.co/NpjS7sw/image-2023-10-04-235935431.png"},
  { name: "The Chinese Terracotta Army", value: 30000000, imageSrc:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528163186890-de9b86b54b51?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dGVycmFjb3R0YSUyMGFybXl8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80"},
];

let item1, item2, correctIndex;

function startNewRound() {
  const index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  let index2;
  do {
    index2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  } while (index2 === index1);
  item1 = items[index1];
  item2 = items[index2];
  // Fade-in animations
  const vsElement = document.querySelector('.vs');
  vsElement.style.animation = 'none';
  void vsElement.offsetWidth; // Trigger reflow
  vsElement.style.animation = null;
  questionTextElement.innerHTML = `${item1.name}`;
  questionTextElement2.innerHTML = `${item2.name}`;
  document.getElementById("item1").textContent = item1.name + " " + formatCurrency(item1.value);
  document.getElementById("item2").textContent = item2.name + " " + formatCurrency(item2.value);
  correctIndex = item1.value > item2.value ? 1 : 0;

  function handleMoreClick() {
    handleItemClick(0, correctIndex);
    showValue(0, correctIndex, item1, item2);
    removeClickListeners();
  }

  function handleLessClick() {
    handleItemClick(1, correctIndex);
    showValue(1, correctIndex, item1, item2);
    removeClickListeners();
  }

  function showValue(clickedIndex, correctIndex, item1, item2) {
    if (clickedIndex === correctIndex) {
      showValueWithAnimation(clickedIndex, correctIndex, item1, item2);
      valueIndex2.innerHTML = `${formatCurrency(item2.value)}`
      valueIndex.innerHTML = `${formatCurrency(item1.value)}`
      document.getElementById("valueIndex").textContent = formatCurrency(item2.value);
      document.getElementById("valueIndex2").textContent = formatCurrency(item1.value);
      valueIndex2.style.display = "block";
      valueIndex.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      valueIndex.style.display = "block";
      valueIndex2.style.display = "block";
      animateValue(valueIndex2, 0, item1.value, 2000); // Animate item2.value 
      animateValue(valueIndex, 0, item2.value, 2000); // Animate item1.value 
      setTimeout(endGame, 4000);
    }
  }

  function formatCurrency(value) {
    return `$${value.toLocaleString()}`;
  }

  function animateValue(element, start, end, duration) {
    let startTimestamp;
    const step = (timestamp) => {
      if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
      const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
      element.textContent = formatCurrency(Math.floor(start + progress * (end - start)));
      if (progress < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

  function showValueWithAnimation(clickedIndex, correctIndex, item1, item2) {
    if (clickedIndex === correctIndex) {
      valueIndex2.style.display = "block";
      valueIndex.style.display = "block";
      animateValue(valueIndex2, 0, item1.value, 2000); // Animate item2.value 
      animateValue(valueIndex, 0, item2.value, 2000); // Animate item1.value 
    } else {
      valueIndex.style.display = "none";
      valueIndex2.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

The only thing you should be really looking at are the `startNewRound()` and `showValue()` functions, the rest is important for bug fixes so i'll leave it here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is a completely different language from JavaScript

Comment: @Barmar that matters how?, i cleary tagged javascript and added a title named javascript

Comment: _"the only thing you should be really looking at is startNewRound() and showValue()"_ in that case you should reduce your [mcve]. Remove everything that's not necessary, like all the animations.

Comment: , i want the animation to stay the same and, everything so there is no bug fixes cuz i'm terrible at them, but if its easier for you i can do it?, do you want me to @jabaa?

Comment: You also wrote "here is the full java you might need". It doesn't affect the problem, it just seemed like you don't know the difference.

Comment: Yes, I want a minimal runnable stack snippet.

Comment: @Barmar, oh sorry my mistake ill edit it out

Comment: After you select `item1`, find its range. Then when selecting `item2`, look for an item in the same range.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every item will have another item in the same range?

Comment: yes, i will add 1000+ items and every item will have another item in the same price range

Comment: Can you fix the code? Currently, it contains a syntax error: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`

Comment: i fixed the error, i did the best i could i'm just a few months into web programming, dont know how to make it work without adding the whole css, html

Comment: The syntax is still invalid. Look at the answer. You probably need around 10 lines of code for a [mcve]. Remove everything that's unrelated to the actual problem. Isolate and analyze the problem without CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select `item1` and find the range it belongs to. Then filter `items` down to the items in the same range and select another random item in that range.

```
item1 = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]; // pick first item
let item_range = priceRanges.find(r => r.min <= item1.value && r.max >= item1.value); // get its range
let filteredItems = items.filter(i => i != item1 && item_range.min <= i.value && item_range.max >= i.value); // filter items to other items in the same range
item2 = filteredItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredItems.length)]; // pick second item
```

Comment: when i paste that in `startNewGame()` it turns into an error where the image wont show up, the text is {item1.name} which is default for my html and {item2.name}

Comment: Are you getting an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: yes, this is the error 
game.js:99 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'min')
    at game.js:99:64
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at startNewRound (game.js:99:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (game.js:522:7)
(anonymous) @ game.js:99
startNewRound @ game.js:99
(anonymous)

Comment: Did you copy my original answer? I had `<=` and `>=` backwards and edited it.

Comment: i also forgot to add the consts 
`const item1Element = document.getElementById("item1"); `
`const item2Element = document.getElementById("item2"); `

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with my answer. All it does is select the items from the array, it has nothing to do with updating the DOM.

Comment: now it seems to work, the price range. But the value wont display, it shows `{item1.value} `and `{item2.value}`

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would do that. It sounds like you wrote a template literal and forgot the `$` before `{item1.value}`.

Comment: no, i have the `$` , this is the error, this is the error game.js:404 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at showValue (game.js:404:40)
    at HTMLButtonElement.handleMoreClick (game.js:277:3)
showValue @ game.js:404
handleMoreClick

Comment: Where does it show that?

Comment: in the console. no erros when i load up but when i click the `more` `less` button it gives me this error

Comment: Are both `item` and `item2` getting values from my code?

Comment: Irt shows `{item1.value}` and `{item2.value}` in the console?

Comment: it shows that in the display game

Comment: That's what I wanted to know -- WHERE in the display does it show that? Which line in your JavaScript is putting the item values in the display?

Comment: yes, the price range works it gets items only the value wont display it shows `{item1.value}` and {item2.value} instead of numbers

Comment: the `showValue()`

Comment: I don't see how that could happen. You call `formatCurrency()` and display the result of that. There's no way that could return the literal string `{item1.value}`.

Comment: BTW, if a value is already a string, there's no need to put it inside backticks when using it.

Comment: i dont know, do you want to move to chat to fix this?, thanks for the tip btw

Comment: I don't think you have enough rep to chat.

Comment: ye not enough rep, but this is the culprit  `animateValue(valueIndex2, 0, item1.value, 2000); // Animate item2.value `
    `animateValue(valueIndex, 0, item2.value, 2000);   // Animate item1.value `

Comment: The only way you'll get that TypeError is if there isn't another item in the same range as `item1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255536/discussion-between-matija-knezevic-and-barmar).